# How to specify the limit of a piecewise function when a point for continuity is given?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to determine if the given function is continuous at the point $(0,0)$. But first, how do I specify the limit for the part ($\frac{\sin{(x^2+y^2)}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$) when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ ?

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{\sin{(x^2+y^2)}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \text{if}\ (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
            1 & \text{if}\ (x,y) = (0,0)
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Comment: The limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}$ is familiar.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$(x^2+y^2)|\cos(x^2+y^2)|\le|\sin(x^2+y^2)|\le x^2+y^2$$

for $x^2+y^2\le \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

With polar cordinate we get $x=\rho \cos { \theta  } ,y=\rho \sin { \theta  } $ $$f\left( x,y \right) =\frac { \sin { (x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 }) }  }{ x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 } } =\frac { \sin { \left( { \rho  }^{ 2 } \right)  }  }{ { \rho  }^{ 2 } } \rightarrow 1=f\left( 0,0 \right) ,\rho \rightarrow 0$$ which shows it is continuous at given point.